# Why does bmkp-desktop-jump change colour scheme?

Tags: themes, bookmarks

I just realised (after playing with different colour themes) that `bmkp-desktop-jump` from [Bookmarks+](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) changes the colour theme to the one selected before - this is nice, but can cause unwanted effects.

Hence, these questions:

1. Where is the colour theme stored? I could not find it in the `bookmarks` file, and it's also not in the `.emacs.desktop` file.
2. How can I disable this?
3. Can I disable this for certain bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

[**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) does nothing with color themes.  And as far as I know, neither does `desktop.el` do anything with them.

- See whether changing the value of option `bmkp-desktop-jump-save-before-flag` makes any difference (I don't think it will).
- However, starting with Emacs 24.4, `desktop.el` can save also frame and window configurations (e.g. frame parameters, which includes face `default`). If you are using Emacs 24.4 or later then check which desktop file you are using. You can use any number of desktop files with **Bookmark+**.
- Check the particular bookmark(s) that lead to this behavior.  You can use `M-x debug-on-entry bmkp-jump-1` to step through the debugger using `d` (and `c` to skip through obvious steps). (Be sure to load the **source** files before using the debugger - it is not so useful if only byte-compiled files are loaded.)

If after investigating you think the behavior really is due to **Bookmark+** then you can follow up with me by email (see the file header).